# Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 9

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to match alphanumeric words separated by the operators, +, -, *, /, <, > and ending with a semicolon. There can be whitespace characters in between e.g. the following strings should return `true`:

```
first + second;
first - second;
first * second;
first / second;
first;
first + second < third;
third < second * first;
```

This is what I have tried:

```java
public boolean isExpr(String line) {
    // factor = ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+)   for example: aasdaa or 23131 or xyz or 1 or a
    // simple-expr = (factor {mulop factor} {addop factor {mulop factor}})
    // expr = simple-expr compop simple-expr | simple-expr

    String factor = new String("([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+)");
    String mulOp = new String("(\\*|\\/)");  // '*'' or '/'
    String addOp = new String("(\\+|\\-)");  // '+' or '-'
    String compOp = new String("(\\<|\\=");  // '<' or '='
    String simpleExpr = new String("(" + factor + " (" + mulOp + " " + factor + ")? (" + addOp + " " + factor + " (" + mulOp + " " + factor + ")?)?");
    String expr = new String("(" + simpleExpr + " " + compOp + " " + simpleExpr + ")|" + simpleExpr);

    System.out.println(line.matches(expr));

    return line.matches(expr);
}
```

What is wrong with that code and how can I solve it?

I got the below error on executing my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 9
((([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+) ((\*|\/) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+))? ((\+|\-) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+) ((\*|\/) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+))?)? (\<|\= (([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+) ((\*|\/) ([A-Za-eZ]+|[0-9]+))? ((\+|\-) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+) ((\*|\/) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+))?)?)|(([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+) ((\*|\/) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0
-9]+))? ((\+|\-) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+) ((\*|\/) ([A-Za-Z]+|[0-9]+))?)?
```

Comment: `A-Za-Z` should be `A-Za-z`

Comment: I updated, still gives error. I'm editing the post. Can you check it again?

Comment: Doing things like `new String"([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+)")` makes no sense at all, `"([A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+)"` already is a string, you don't need create a new one, and doing so is a waste of time and memory. The same goes for all you other uses of `new String(...)`. The only constructor of String you should ever need to call is one that takes a byte array and a character set.

Comment: For debugging and analyzing regular expressions, I strongly recommend you to use some kind of visual tool, .e.g [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), since regex strings tend to be hard to read past 20 characters.

Comment: Count parenthesis and you should easily find place where it doesn't match. Also please don't change question about one problem into question about other problem. Harsh reality of this site is that it isn't to help only question asker but mostly to help people facing same problem in the future. So we try to gather questions about *single* problem per "topic" (even if your current problem will be solved and new one will appear you should ask about new problem in separate question - and yes you may need to wait to ask new question).

Comment: @Pshemo I see, but I tought that creating new question for same problem would be unnecessary and pollutes the site.

Comment: "but I tought that creating new question for *same problem* would be unnecessary" first version of the question was *describing problem related to `a-Z`*. After *fixing that* problem you asked about *separate one* (regardless if its cause was in code already, your *question* wasn't about it earlier).

Comment: You're right. What should I do now? Should I close the question and create new one?

Comment: Since only posted answer is about *second* problem probably no one will get angry if you change question into problem which was being pointed out by in that answer (and don't forget to also update question title since currently it is about first problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Your logic is unnecessarily complex and error-prone.

I suggest you, instead of using unnecessarily complex and error-prone logic,  simply use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vQuYGH/1), `[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s*[\/*+\-<>]\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*)*;` which covers all the example strings you have posted in the question.

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `[A-Za-z0-9]+`: 1+ alphabets or digits
- `(?:`: Open non-capturing group

  - `\s*`: 0+ whitespace characters
  - `[\/*+\-<>]`: One of `/`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `<`, `>`
  - `\s*`: 0+ whitespace characters
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+`: 1+ alphabets or digits
  - `\s*`: 0+ whitespace characters
- `)`: Close non-capturing group
- `*`: Quantifier to make the non-capturing group match 0+ times
- `;`: The charcter literal, `;`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "first + second;",
                    "first * second;",
                    "first - second;",
                    "first / second;",
                    "first;",
                    "first + second < third;",
                    "third < second * first;"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(isExpr(s)));      
    }

    public static boolean isExpr(String line) {
        return line.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\\s*[\\/*+\\-<>]\\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\\s*)*;");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

### What went wrong with your code?

Because of the unnecessarily complex logic that you have implemented, one or more of the parentheses in the final regex have not been closed. In addition to that, I can see at least one part where the parenthesis has not been closed e.g.

```
String compOp = new String("(\\<|\\=");  // '<' or '='
```

It should be

```
String compOp = new String("(\\<|\\=)");  // '<' or '='
//----------------------------------^
```

Apart from this, given below are a couple of more things that you should learn/address:

1. You can simplify the initialization like:

```
String factor = "[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+";
String mulOp = "\\*|\\/";  // '*'' or '/'
String addOp = "\\+|\\-";  // '+' or '-'
String compOp = "\\<|\\=";  // '<' or '='
```

2. Change `a-Z` to `a-z`.

Comment: There are actually four missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: I updated, still gives error. I'm editing the post. Can you check it again?

Comment: @lapestand - Your code looks unnecessarily complex. Let me know what value you are passing to `String line` and I will suggest you a simpler code.

Comment: @lapestand - And, what is your expected output (`true`/`false`) for this string?

Comment: Sorry, It should be true. Because it corresponds to factor + factor which is simple-expr